# Ionic4 build error: Undefined SCSS variable in page.scss

Tags: sass, ionic4

I created a blank Ionic4 app and in the `src/global.scss`, I declare a variable `$padding: 16px`. I then tried to use the $padding in an element in `home.page.scss` as follows:

```
.highlight {
  padding: $padding;
}
```

I expected it to output the following as it does in Ionic3:

```
.highlight {
  padding: 16px;
}
```

Instead in Ionic4 I am getting an undefined variable on the $padding during the build process. Can we not use global SCSS variables within the page styles anymore or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the global.scss file in your page.scss file to get it work

```
@import '../../global.scss';
```

Since global.scss already include for the project. So the solution is that you make a new file **common.scss** and import it inside page.scss with

```
@import '../../common.scss';
```

And inside common.scss you can type

```
$padding: 16px
```

Comment: Not ideal as I was hoping it would would like Ionic3 but I have come to realise that Ionic4 prefers CSS4 variables by default but this methods works for the time being. For anyone using it, make sure the common.scss doesn't have actual styles or it will be duplicated.